# When are initializations outside a constructor called?

Tags: java, constructor

Suppose I have

```
class MyObject
{
    Object object1 = new Object();
    Object object2;

    public MyObject()
    {
        object2 = new Object();
    }

    public MyObject(Object object2)
    {
        this.object2 = object2;
    }

    public MyObject(Object object1, Object object2)
    {
        this.object1 = object1;
        this.object2 = object2;
    }
}
```

When does `object1` get initialized? Before `object2`, after `object2`, depends?

What happens if I have a constructor that conflicts with the global definition of `object1`, e.g. in the third constructor above. Which value does `object` take?

This isn't causing me any problems but I just wanted to understand the language a bit better. I like to know these little things so that I could potentially make use of them later on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The variables are initialized to the default values for their type (0, null etc)
- First the superclass constructor is called. If the superclass constructor calls any virtual methods overridden in this class, the override will see the default values, regardless of any variable initializers or initialization in the constructor body.
- Then variable initializers are executed.
- Then the constructor body is executed.

So if you change the value of a variable within the constructor body, any value set by the variable initializer will be overwritten. (The previous value could have been used in other chained constructors etc, of course.)

See [section 12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) of the JLS for more details.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *overwritten* instead of *ignored*?

Comment: @LukasKnuth: I was trying to get across the idea that the initialization is pointless, but actually in some cases it could have other effects... will edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to confirm behavior, use [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) or a similar tool to inspect the bytecode. Though [Jon is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11810737/304), refer to the specification as a first port of call.

```
Compiled from "MyObject.java"
class MyObject {
  java.lang.Object object1;

  java.lang.Object object2;

  public MyObject();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #11               // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0
       5: new           #3                // class java/lang/Object
       8: dup
       9: invokespecial #11               // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      12: putfield      #13               // Field object1:Ljava/lang/Object;
      15: aload_0
      16: new           #3                // class java/lang/Object
      19: dup
      20: invokespecial #11               // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
      23: putfield      #15               // Field object2:Ljava/lang/Object;
      26: return
```